# How can we use models which is created in Vertex AI inside dialog flow generators?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, dialogflow-cx

I have created and deployed a model in Vertex AI using my text dataset. Is there a way that I can use this model in Dialogflow CX Generators - Model configuration?

I have attached a screenshot that shows where I expect my model to be displayed.

[Please refer to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcISN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not an option for now. If you want to use a custom model deployed on vertex AI you will have to create a webhook and call the model there